# Desktop elements stop working after wake from suspend

Tags: 18.04, gnome, xorg

When I wake my laptop from suspend on 18.04 LTS (gnome), desktop elements stop working. The system bar at the top doesn’t recognize clicks, the dock doesn’t work, and the only way to interact with the DE is through keyboard shortcuts until I restart the system.
Things I’ve tried from looking up the issue:

- Reverting to x11 from wayland
- Enabling/disabling dash to    dock/appindicators
- Installing and reconfiguring plymouth (since I used to get an error for it and a similar question marked that as the answer)

I’m aware of similar questions but none of their answers were effective for me so far.